# Joining field to a polygon shapefile from another overlapping polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-processing, spatial-join

I have two polygon shapefiles (parcel and zoning). Parcel shapefile is overlapped by zoning shapefile. Parcel layer does not contain information about zone and I want to add that information to each parcel from zoning shapefile.

My idea is to create centroids from parcel shapefiles and after that to join zoning shapefile by location. On that way, I will add zoning attributes in my centroid point file. When I finish that I will join by location that point file and my parcel file. Unnecessary fields could be deleted after that.

I need to know is there any faster way to finish this job in QGIS?

This is a screenshot of a part of my parcel shapefile:
[image]

This is a screenshot of a part of my zoning shapefile:
[image]

Just to note that this is a very large data, about 800000 parcels.

Comment: Why don't you directly join the two polygon shapefiles? It should be enough if your layers have the same crs. In addition, the creation of centroids could lead to inaccurate results in some situations.

Comment: You mean to join two shapefiles by location? Could you describe how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some sort number or ID number that you can use to join tables?

Comment: I don`t have some unique value in both shapefiles.

Comment: Also if I go to Vector- Data Managment Tools- Join Attributes by Location and after that use Take attributes of first located feature I have some wrong results. For example, road have joined attributes of nearest zones, even they don`t need any zone information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your parcels and zoning shapefiles have the same crs, you may use the **Join attributes by location** algorithm from **Processing Toolbox.**

You may set these parameters:

[image]

The output layer will be identical to the *parcels* layer but, in addition, it will have the same fields of the *zoning* layer and, when two features from both layers intersect, it will store the corresponding value from the *zoning* layer. From a general point of view, this operation should be enough for accomplishing this task.